# SSIS transformation (almost like a pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following data coming in to SSIS

```
Set   Value
---   -------
1     One
1     Two
1     Three
2     Four
2     Five
2     Six
```

I want to transform it to read

```
Set   ValueList
---   -------
1     One, Two, Three
2     Four, Five, Six
```

How do I do this in SSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Script Component to do the string concatenation across rows

```
string TagId = "-1";
string TagList = "";
bool IsFirstRow = true;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.TAGSId.ToString() == TagId)
    {
        TagList += Row.TAG + ",";
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsFirstRow)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            IsFirstRow = false;
        }

        TagId = Row.TAGSId.ToString();
        TagList = Row.TAG.ToString() + ",";
    }

    Output0Buffer.TagId = int.Parse(TagId);
    Output0Buffer.TagList = TagList;
    Output0Buffer.TagLength = TagList.Length;

    //variable used in subsequent queries
    this.Variables.TagList = TagList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a pivot task in the data flow transformations. You could try it, but I'll warn you that we have been less than hapy with it's implementation.

Alternatively, you could use the dataflow to put the data into a staging table, and pivot using SQL or do the pivot in the SQL you use to create the incoming data source. If you want to do it in SQl code, this might help:

```
select 1 as Item 
into #test 
union select 2 
union select 3 
union select 4 
union select 5 

select STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + cast(Item as nvarchar) 
        FROM #test 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Since it is coming in from an XML file, I could not do the XML PATH technique. I used the SCRIPT component to achieve what I wanted.