# How to process data in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis, pivot

Need to convert data from the below format

From

```
1,Delivery Confirmation Email
5,11/09/2018 07:10
7,OOLU1939921
9,S00224239
```

To

```
Event: Delivery Confirmation Email;
Date: 11/09/2018 07:10;
Container: OOLU1939921;
Job: S00224239
```

or in a table format as

```
Event                          Date              Container        Job         
Delivery Confirmation Email    11/09/2018 07:10  OOLU1939921      S00224239
```

Is it possible through pivot in ssis?

Comment: what is the source type for data? Flat file, DB-Table or something else?

Comment: it's a text file which i processed from an html file

Comment: What are the columns and rows?  What are the names of the columns?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : column names are Event,date,Container,Job
row: Delivery confirmation emal, 11/09/2018,ooLUI939921,S00224239

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question with answers suggesting a script task or an ELT approach

[SSIS transformation (almost like a pivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726858/ssis-transformation-almost-like-a-pivot)

You can try and implement the script transformation if you wish. Personally I prefer an ELT approach

1. Create a staging table with three columns:

.

```
CREATE TABLE DeliveryConfirmationStaging
(
ID INT NOT NULL,
StringValue VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DTInserted DATETIME2(0) DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

2. Load your text file into that table with a CSV source and an ADO SQL Server destination in a data flow.
3. Add a SQL script before your data flow with `TRUNCATE TABLE DeliveryConfirmationStaging;` in it
4. Lastly add this SQL script after your data flow which transforms it with SQL (borrowing @GordonLinoff answer)

.

```
insert into yourfinaltable (event, date,container,job)
select max(case when col1 = 1 then col2 end) as event,
       TRY_CAST(max(case when col1 = 5 then col2 end) as datetime) as [date],
       max(case when col1 = 7 then col2 end) as container,
       max(case when col1 = 9 then col2 end) as job
from DeliveryConfirmationStaging;
```

You don't mention what date format this is. Is it September 11th or 9th November?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when col1 = 1 then col2 end) as event,
       max(case when col1 = 5 then col2 end) as date,
       max(case when col1 = 7 then col2 end) as container,
       max(case when col1 = 9 then col2 end) as job
from t;
```

Comment: did you mean the above code can be implemented in ssis? Sorry I am newbie to SSIS and i couldn't find an option of conditional aggregation.

Comment: @Drishya . . . Your question is tagged "sql", so I assume a SQL solution meets your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the problem through Pivot transformation in ssis.